# how to use function parameter for getting data for json file in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, function

sorry if the question is bit disturbing or not asked right since i really didn't knew what to write ,
so i have a function which have a parameter inside it I want to call a specific value from a json file
for example :
data = to the fetched data/json

```
test = (ex) =>{
data_wanted = data.ex;
}
```

since in my situation since ex always changes i need to use it in that way, and when i do that it gives me  **Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**,
really sorry for the very poor explanation but really know anything what this problem called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats ok. It's complicated to search the solution to a problem that you really doesnt know how to describe.

I'll give you an example about how o access data from json files using node.js

You'll need a function that reads your local file (if your json is a real file)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readData = (filePath) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return null;
      }
      return JSON.parse(data);
    })
}
```

Now, the way that you was trying to access the data inside the json file was apparently correct. I did this example:

```
const findDataInJson = () => {
    const myJson = readData('./jsonPath');

    //Example Json:
    // {
    //     test: "tested",
    //     test2: [
    //         {
    //             test: "test2-0"
    //         },
    //         {
    //             test: "test2-1"
    //         },
    //         {
    //             test: "test2-2"
    //         }
    //     ]
    // }

    console.log(myJson.test) // tested
    console.log(myJson.test2) // [{ test: "test2-0" }, { test: "test2-1" }, { test: "test2-2" }]
    console.log(myJson.test2[0]) // { test: "test2-0" }
    console.log(myJson.test2[2]) // { test: "test2-2" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by doing this

```
test = (ex) =>{
data_wanted = data["ex"];
}
```